# If e.keyCode is the "enter" button and the element contains other text the condition is verified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyup

I use `keyup()` method on `input` element:

i would like to know if is possible to do that the button pressed is `enter` **but** the input field is not empty then alert a variable. I tried:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(e) { //#search is id input
  if (($('#search').val() != "") && (e.keyCode == 13)) {
    alert($('#search').val());   //alert
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
  }
});
```

Doesn't work... because the condition is true also if the input element is empty :/

This is jsfiddle if you want help me:
https://jsfiddle.net/0br6q72r/

Sorry for my english and thanks a lot! :)

Comment: use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`

Comment: @shu i tried but nothing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `keydown` event instead and the values should have to be `.trim()`ed the values if it contains whitespaces:

```js
$('#search').keydown(function(e) {
  if (this.value.trim().length == 0 && e.keyCode == 13) { // <--ensures if no values entered and hit enter key
    e.preventDefault(); // then stop the process
  } else if (e.keyCode == 13) { // check if key is enter, it is required
                                // as it enable user to put search inputs.
    alert($('#search').val()); // then alert the value
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); // and submit the form
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action='http://www.google.com' accept-charset="UTF-8" method="get" target='_blank' id='cse-search-box'>
  <input type='text' id="search" name='q' size='50' />
</form>
```

#### [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/0br6q72r/5/)

Comment: i add .trim() but nothing... if you show me an example is better

Comment: i guess the issue is `keyup` you can use `keydown` instead but trimming the value is also good to have.

Comment: and with "e.preventDefault();" than i can't write in the input

Comment: @user3162975 yup just updated the fiddle. check that one. https://jsfiddle.net/0br6q72r/2/

Comment: _doesn't work..... :/_ This actually doesn't help. You should add more details what you expect from it.

Comment: what details ? with your code if i press enter and the input field is empty a new window is open (so doesn't work). I write all details in first post no ? i tried all your example and edit but nothing

Comment: @user3162975 you need to have two conditions. https://jsfiddle.net/0br6q72r/5/ check this one.

Comment: you are great, i think I would never have understood or it would take me a long time... thanks a lot ! you are very kind

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#search').keyup(function (e) { //#search is id input
                if (($('#search').val().trim() != "") && (e.keyCode == 13)) {
                    alert($('#search').val());   //alert
                   // $(this).closest('form').submit();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="search" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```